# Python Automated Obtain the confirmation number using Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to send requests for the site and  Received an email containing the confirmation number
I tried this code:

```
    # coding=utf-8


import json
import requests
from requests.sessions import Session


url = "https://do.blsspainvisa.com/book_appointment.php"
payload = {
'app_type': 'Individual',
'member': '2',
'centre': '21#21',
'category': 'Normal',
'phone_code': '1',
'phone': '555555555',
'email': '8ddd336866@emailtown.club',
'verification_code': 'Request+verification+code',
'otp':'',
'g-recaptcha-response': '03AHaCkAYAC1g6xGRap0tIgFDWOOKxYFui0v9sfI0V7CHSvVYJawQCJLuQYS3FnOArzfOxdoMVOwEF05cP8k8Ft-pS06RXNGxRUZoUw5wT8tq17K3Su_obiyKmgIpkgf7jTu0lFbDEtLK4lAsd-rweqyxGuISTP5HNZRCln1TYkt6Mp4TIv9C7h45QLhJqEo031HO6IgF7FjJ_uEzGHhkP9j47AfQd6PvXJDTNKTLkqjLi654U5rrRQWincridLDEnOgEF5HfGi2tV2KpRBJYKdZH1NDJdDfAQfbO86q58eEbu9YLwUAKDXz91DC7Lk7S2rSnYgpbwZWJSPDGLKrmA00JFeOGyz44Q-5abNEBkPopM7QzOL5U4HK8zC9asWT9ffq6vyldD3gRG',
'countryID':' ',

}


headers = {

'Host': 'do.blsspainvisa.com',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0',
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language': 'fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Content-Length': '598',
'Origin': 'https://do.blsspainvisa.com',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Referer': 'https://do.blsspainvisa.com/book_appointment.php',
'Cookie': 'AWSALB=iD7TuVZ4hCKgHx2+OLC7ifQyHQ0UkKsKtEce7wRYrajyuf/MVVaN+SG8dL1oOk6MXGl3lnAiwU7J8fvhpsYidtXGH7YHatrR77vQArNJFFJyovAkdzpTTSmODxXe; AWSALBCORS=iD7TuVZ4hCKgHx2+OLC7ifQyHQ0UkKsKtEce7wRYrajyuf/MVVaN+SG8dL1oOk6MXGl3lnAiwU7J8fvhpsYidtXGH7YHatrR77vQArNJFFJyovAkdzpTTSmODxXe; _ga=GA1.2.168511806.1585048112; PHPSESSID=06ktlbrn7os104skvduqq7qai2; _gid=GA1.2.2137636513.1585652017',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',

}




r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(r.status_code)
```

But I did not receive any mail

Where is the error in the code?

Comment: are you sure the catcha response is that? does it not change?

Comment: I'm not sure. How do I know؟

Comment: Open the site for you to see  do.blsspainvisa.com

Comment: well how did you get that value the first time?

Comment: I pressed on verification_code

Comment: try that again and see if its the same

Comment: g-recaptcha-response "03AHaCkAaQwWIoR38I-zRo3RSuSCEetJ7FSUYFWPcQ52cPTWyEJAwR5iS-vYvupdMSGVt4DLcmtFWu_I7WW0C6r9JRYzVZ2OCCz9nulOrIv9uSnb7oNcrUoXMW-H3DZrieoVpXnMiiT9EQaOlPElKmI23U_zcO8wSXn6KJN7JeLpiLRRAoD8D1T6pvtHeCttORD2jt6Dd4QaYbHeJa9lb8APL_ZyM9l9BY7Sy-T52V1R-sH1aEmsVgVWGzpdj3jmj8CpZlFApSN3qufpsDolqyJb9eGm-_FkaAZiDNy4RLMs3cJr71XOw2wXdyd22oWqD5tL6H7OSyskn1C9IGq6Rtfnw1q2bKwgqyocDcm2Hfa5iF1L0dXRF6eCUjLJyGdwIMm_SM9V9gtNuS"

Comment: thats different than the first one, so you're going to have to get that dynamically

Comment: recaptcha invisible  How to get it dynamically؟

Comment: use recaptcha api to get the captcha g-recaptcha response dynamically. https://2captcha.com/2captcha-api#solving_recaptchav2_new